# Azure Worker Role compatibillity with .Net 4.5.2

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

In visual studio (with Azure SDK 2.2 and 2.3 installed) I am getting an error trying to run an Azure Worker Role:

> The role X is using an unsupported TargetFrameworkVersion v4.5.2

Should I be getting this with the latest SDK?  Is there a date for when compatibility will be provided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that 4.5.2 isn't supported yet. According to this [Microsoft blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx) they hope to add this version soon.

Comment: Update: 4.5.2 appears to be supported on Family 4 of the Guest OS (Server 2012 R2) with a caveat that it hasn't been "officially" tested but that it is supported by Azure support.

Comment: @JasonCoder yea but it still wont build in vs, even updated the sdk to the latest

Answer (score 12):

Azure SDK 2.6 only allows you to build the .NET 4.5.2 package. You still need to add a startup script and manually install the framework.

See for now: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-install-dotnet/

**UPDATE APRIL 2015**

Use Azure 2.6 SDK (3)

> With Azure SDK 2.6 you can develop cloud service applications (PaaS)
>   targeting .NET 4.5.2 or .NET 4.6 provided that you manually install
>   the target .NET Framework on the Cloud Service Role. See Install .NET
>   on a Cloud Service Role.

**UPDATE NOV 2014**

They did not add support in SDK 2.5.

> Using Azure SDK version 2.5 you can develop IaaS applications targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2 or .NET Framework 4.5.3, provided that you install the target .NET Framework on the Azure virtual machines that run them. ***.NET Framework 4.5.1 is the most recent supported target framework for PaaS applications developed using this version of the SDK*** (2)

This was supposed to be released today with 2.5 SDK (1)

> At currently, we couldn't create and deploy azure cloud service using .net 4.5.2, this will be supported when azure sdk 2.5 released.

However it still fails to package even with 2.5 installed.

(1) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9eab0cd9-c312-4901-95e6-5df2a29f7135/how-to-build-and-deploy-web-or-worker-roles-using-net-452?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

(2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx

(3) http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/azure-sdk-dotnet-release-notes-2_6/

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the place to keep an eye on this is via the Guest OS releases.   .NET 4.5.2 will not be supported until a version of the Guest OS is released that supports it.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix/

See the Guest OS Versions table.  Current latest is:

```
FAMILY 4
Windows Server 2012 R2
Supports .NET 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1
```

Comment: The above linked page is scheduled for deletion, its successor can be found here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix/

Answer (score 2):

Folks, apologies for the delayed response on this topic.

Currently, Cloud Services doesn't officially support .NET 4.5.2. We are currently evaluating supporting .NET 4.5.2 on the existing Guest OS family 4. I will keep you posted when I find out more.

In the meanwhile, if you are interested in using .NET 4.5.2, one option is to download it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642 and install it via startup tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The November Guest OS release is targeted to support 4.5.2 out of the box, so no need to use start up task.

I believe you also need to upgrade to 2.6 sdk to be able to use 4.5.2.

http://sxp.microsoft.com/feeds/3.0/msdntn/WindowsAzureOSUpdates

> On August 7, 2014, Microsoft announced that support will end for .NET
>   Framework 4, 4.5, and 4.5.1 on January 12, 2016. To ensure that your
>   cloud services continue to be secure and protected, Azure will update
>   the .NET Framework in Windows Azure Guest operating system (Guest OS)
>   family 2.x, 3.x and 4.x to .NET Framework 4.5.2 in November Guest OS
>   Release. Cloud services running on Guest OS family 2.x, 3.x and 4.x
>   with automatic updates enabled will be updated to the November Guest
>   OS with .NET Framework 4.5.2. If you have concerns of possible
>   application compatibility issues of the .NET update, we would suggest
>   you to validate your cloud service with .NET 4.5.2 before November
>   Patch Tuesday, Nov 10, 2015.

Update: something went wrong and Microsoft pushed this back to the January OS Family now.

Comment: Ah...nuts...so this has now gone from a question of "why can't I have it", to a case of "get yourself upgraded immediately". :(